# Get security groups members Domain\Username

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have script that get all members of security groups across domains and export to `CSV file` in this format: `Name, username, security group`.  But I want to  add another row for the domain so format will look like this: `domain\username, name, security group`.

I could get the DN but I am only interested in just `domain\username`. I search around in the internet and I couldn't find anything and I am not sure if this even possible

```
$objForest = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest() $DomainList = @($objForest.Domains | Select-Object Name) $Domains = $DomainList | foreach {$_.Name}
$Groups = Import-Csv C:\ad.csv
$Table = @()
$Record = @{   "Group Name" = ""   "Name" = ""   "Username" = "" }

Foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
  $Arrayofmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $Group.groupad
-recursive  -Server $Domain | select name,samaccountname
  foreach ($Member in $Arrayofmembers) {
    $Record."Group Name" = $Group.ad
    $Record."Name" = $Member.name
    $Record."UserName" = $Member.samaccountname
    $objRecord = New-Object PSObject -property $Record
    $Table += $objrecord
  } 
}

$Table | export-csv "C:\SecurityGroups3.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: when you get the DN, use regex to get the DC then -join with the username.

Comment: Thanks Burn for your quick response, I am new to powershell so could you be kind enough and give me example how to user regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Bum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5652557/bum) mentioned, you can use a regex to get the `DC` and combine it with the username:

```
$username = 'Michael'
$distinguishedName = 'CN=Domain Admins,CN=Users,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com'

$dc = [regex]::Match($distinguishedName, 'DC=([^,|$]+)').Groups[1].Value
$domainuser = '{0}\{1}' -f $dc, $username
```

Output of `$domainuser`:

```
$domainuser
Fabrikam\Michael
```

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you so much for your assistance but now I have another issue with the script. some of these ADgroups have nested groups and when I use recursive it list all members of the nested group under the main AD group but I want to show the name of the nested group that they are belong to? I am new to the site and I am not sure if I should post another question for this issue or I should use the same thread. anyway thank you for your assistance and looking forward for your reply. I have the final script but not sure how to posted it. it want accept it in the comment field for it size

Comment: Hey Yallabina, glad to help you. You should probably ask a new question. This will give you the most attention. I will try to help you

Comment: Thank you for your quick response:) I will post it now

Comment: Hope I can help you again.